# Isomorphism between $K\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R}$ and $K_{\mathbb{R}}$, Minkowski theory

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, tensor-products

This is a basic question from Neukirch’s book ‘Algebraic Number theory’, chapter 1, $\S$5.

Let $K$ be a number field, $K_{\mathbb{C}}$ the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $\prod_{\tau}{\mathbb{C}}$ where $\tau$ vary over Hom$(K, \mathbb{C})$ and let $j:K \rightarrow K_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the mapping $a \mapsto (\tau a)$. There is an involution $F$ on $K_{\mathbb{C}}$ which sends $z=(z_{\tau})$ to $Fz$ where $(Fz)_{\tau}=\bar{z}_{\bar{\tau}}$. Define $K_{\mathbb{R}}$ to be the $\mathbb{R}$- vector space consisting of the Gal$(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$- invariant points of $K_{\mathbb{C}}$.

On page 30, it states that $j$ gives rise to an identification $$J:K\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R}\simeq K_{\mathbb{R}},\quad\quad a\otimes x\mapsto j(a)x.$$

I can see that the $\mathbb{Q}$- bilinear map $K\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow K_{\mathbb{R}},\; (a,x)\mapsto j(a)x$ gives rise to the $\mathbb{Q}$ (and $\mathbb{R}$)-linear map above, but why is $J$ an isomorphism? I tried to construct an inverse but this seems hard to do.

Even to show that $J$ is injective seems hard. I also tried to show that $K_{\mathbb{R}}$ satisfies the UMP for the tensor product, but again, I got stuck. The problem is that it’s not clear if the coordinates $z_{\tau}$ of an element $z\in K_{\mathbb{R}}$ are in the images of $\tau$.

Is there a way to show that $J$ is an isomorphism?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

With more thinking, I believe the only easy way to understand this is the following.

- The primitive element theorem is not needed but it is clearer with it. So $K=\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]\cong\Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)$. Factorize in irreducibles $f=\prod_i f_i\in\Bbb{R}[x]$. The main point is that $$j(\prod_{i\ne l} f_i(\alpha))=\prod_{i\ne l}j(f_i(\alpha)))$$ is non-zero in only one (pair of) complex embedding, the one sending $\alpha$ to a root of $f_l$.

Whence the surjectivity follows.

- Compare the dimensions, one is $\dim_\Bbb{R} (K\otimes_\Bbb{Q}\Bbb{R})=[K:\Bbb{Q}]$ the other is $\dim_\Bbb{R}(K_\Bbb{R})=|Hom_\Bbb{Q}(K,\Bbb{C})|$, both are equal so $J$ is a (real-algebra) isomorphism.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your first bullet point. I see that $K\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R} \simeq \prod_{i}\mathbb{R}[x]/(f_{i})$, but what is $l$ that appears in the product? And how is the surjectivity of $J$ deduced? Thanks.